# How to optimize an sql query with OR in where to filter on values from different columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

General context: I'm having a postgres-database which includes a knowledge system (skos). The knowledge system is in a different scheme. skos describes all the links between concepts, how they are related and also includes notes, notations, labels, ... . Each concept is mapped to this skos. 
When querying the actual business logic, which is about Cascades, CascadeSteps, Technologies, Additives, ..., I want to include the translations for each of these concepts in the response. 
I'm adding views to simplify the requests.

In one of the queries, this is the bottleneck (this is a part of the full query):

```sql
    SELECT   trcs.cascade,
             "Translations".language,
             jsonb_object_agg("Translations".code, "Translations".skos) AS resource
    FROM     "CascadeStep" trcs 
    LEFT JOIN "CascadeUnit" trcu 
           ON trcu.cuid = trcs.from
    LEFT JOIN "TechnologyAdditive" trta on trta.technology = trcu.technology
    LEFT JOIN skos."Translations"
           ON (skos."Translations".id = trcs.from) OR
              (skos."Translations".id = trcs.flow) OR
              (skos."Translations".id = trcs.product) OR
              (skos."Translations".id = trta.additive)
    WHERE     skos."Translations".notation = 'SimpleNotation'
    GROUP BY  trcs.cascade, "Translations".language)
```

The reason seems to be the `OR` in the filter. When I analyze:

```
HASH JOIN  | 29 %

Left join on ((trcs."from")::bpchar = (trcu.cuid)::bpchar)

Hash Join Node joins to record sets by hashing one of them (using a Hash Scan).
Node Type   Hash Join
Parent Relationship Outer
Parallel Aware  false
Join Type   Left
Startup Cost    43.02
Total Cost  191.84
Plan Rows   1620
Plan Width  72
Actual Startup Time 0.468
Actual Total Time   12.035
Actual Rows 598
Actual Loops    1
Output  trcs.cascade,"Translations".language,"Translations".code,"Translations".skos
Inner Unique    false
Hash Cond   ((trcs."from")::bpchar = (trcu.cuid)::bpchar)
Filter  (("Translations".id = (trcs."from")::bpchar) OR ("Translations".id = (trcs.flow)::bpchar) OR ("Translations".id = (trcs.product)::bpchar) OR ("Translations".id = (trta.additive)::bpchar))
```

I tried to use different strategies in that where clause, but none of them seems to produce better results:

```
 ... on skos."Translations".id = any(array[trcs.from, trcs.flow, trcs.product, trta.additive])
```

is about 1.25x slower.

```
  ... on skos."Translations".id in (select trcs.from union all select  trcs.flow union all select trcs.product union all select trta.additive)
```

is 2-5x slower

```
 ... on skos."Translations".id in (select trcs.from 
                                   union all 
                                   select  trcs.flow 
                                   union all 
                                   select trcs.product 
                                   union all 
                                   select trta.additive 
                                   from "TechnologyAdditive" trta 
                                   left join "CascadeUnit" trcu on trcu.cuid=trcs.from
                                   where trta.technology = trcu.technology)
```

10-30x slower

The actual question: is it possible to efficiently use different columns in the `where` clause of the query, to replace the `OR`s, or can the query be rewritten more efficiently?

**== EDIT: add (relevant) output of `explain (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)`**

```
Hash  (cost=200.55..200.55 rows=966 width=61) (actual time=13.467..13.467 rows=21 loops=1)
Output: i18n.language, i18n.resource, i18n.cascade
Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 29kB
Buffers: shared hit=12
->  Subquery Scan on i18n  (cost=194.27..200.55 rows=966 width=61) (actual time=13.340..13.450 rows=21 loops=1)
      Output: i18n.language, i18n.resource, i18n.cascade
      Buffers: shared hit=12
      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=194.27..197.66 rows=966 width=61) (actual time=13.339..13.447 rows=21 loops=1)
            Output: trcs.cascade, "Translations".language, jsonb_object_agg("Translations".code, "Translations".skos)
            Group Key: trcs.cascade, "Translations".language
            Buffers: shared hit=12
            ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=43.02..191.84 rows=1620 width=72) (actual time=0.452..12.193 rows=598 loops=1)
                  Output: trcs.cascade, "Translations".language, "Translations".code, "Translations".skos
                  Hash Cond: ((trcs."from")::bpchar = (trcu.cuid)::bpchar)
                  Filter: (("Translations".id = (trcs."from")::bpchar) OR ("Translations".id = (trcs.flow)::bpchar) OR ("Translations".id = (trcs.product)::bpchar) OR ("Translations".id = (trta.additive)::bpchar))
                  Rows Removed by Filter: 19802
                  Buffers: shared hit=12
                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.32..55.40 rows=7498 width=176) (actual time=0.344..4.213 rows=13040 loops=1)
                        Output: trcs.cascade, trcs."from", trcs.flow, trcs.product, "Translations".language, "Translations".code, "Translations".skos, "Translations".id
                        Buffers: shared hit=10
                        ->  Seq Scan on public."CascadeStep" trcs  (cost=0.00..5.49 rows=163 width=104) (actual time=0.004..0.076 rows=163 loops=1)
                              Output: trcs.cascade, trcs."from", trcs.flow, trcs.product
                              Buffers: shared hit=5
                        ->  Materialize  (cost=23.32..23.69 rows=46 width=72) (actual time=0.002..0.009 rows=80 loops=163)
                              Output: "Translations".language, "Translations".code, "Translations".skos, "Translations".id
                              Buffers: shared hit=5
                              ->  Subquery Scan on "Translations"  (cost=23.32..23.64 rows=46 width=72) (actual time=0.337..0.520 rows=80 loops=1)
                                    Output: "Translations".language, "Translations".code, "Translations".skos, "Translations".id
                                    Buffers: shared hit=5
                                    ->  Group  (cost=23.32..23.50 rows=46 width=117) (actual time=0.336..0.508 rows=80 loops=1)
                                          Output: l.concept_nss, l.language, n."notationType", n.value, jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('prefLabel', l.label, 'definition', v.object)), v.object
                                          Group Key: l.concept_nss, n."notationType", l.language, v.object, n.value
                                          Buffers: shared hit=5
                                          ->  Sort  (cost=23.32..23.34 rows=46 width=108) (actual time=0.329..0.337 rows=80 loops=1)
                                                Output: l.concept_nss, l.language, n."notationType", n.value, v.object, l.label
                                                Sort Key: l.concept_nss, l.language, v.object, n.value
                                                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 37kB
                                                Buffers: shared hit=5
                                                ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=10.41..23.07 rows=46 width=108) (actual time=0.155..0.182 rows=80 loops=1)
                                                      Output: l.concept_nss, l.language, n."notationType", n.value, v.object, l.label
                                                      Hash Cond: ((n_1.concept_nss = n.concept_nss) AND (v.lang = l.language))
                                                      Buffers: shared hit=5
                                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=7.53..20.18 rows=4 width=96) (actual time=0.025..0.031 rows=12 loops=1)
                                                            Output: n_1.concept_nss, v.object, v.lang
                                                            Inner Unique: true
                                                            Hash Cond: (v.note_id = n_1.id)
                                                            Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                            ->  Seq Scan on skos."NoteValue" v  (cost=0.00..12.25 rows=750 width=80) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=12 loops=1)
                                                                  Output: v.lang, v.object, v.note_id
                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1
                                                            ->  Hash  (cost=7.52..7.52 rows=4 width=48) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=12 loops=1)
                                                                  Output: n_1.id, n_1.concept_nss
                                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=2
                                                                  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on skos."Note" n_1  (cost=2.04..7.52 rows=4 width=48) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=12 loops=1)
                                                                        Output: n_1.id, n_1.concept_nss
                                                                        Recheck Cond: (n_1.type = 'skos_definition'::text)
                                                                        Heap Blocks: exact=1
                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=2
                                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "Note_property_concept_key"  (cost=0.00..2.04 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=13 loops=1)
                                                                              Index Cond: (n_1.type = 'skos_definition'::text)
                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=1
                                                      ->  Hash  (cost=2.69..2.69 rows=46 width=102) (actual time=0.124..0.124 rows=80 loops=1)
                                                            Output: n."notationType", n.value, n.concept_nss, l.concept_nss, l.language, l.label
                                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 19kB
                                                            Buffers: shared hit=2
                                                            ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1.34..2.69 rows=46 width=102) (actual time=0.051..0.093 rows=80 loops=1)
                                                                  Output: n."notationType", n.value, n.concept_nss, l.concept_nss, l.language, l.label
                                                                  Hash Cond: (l.concept_nss = n.concept_nss)
                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=2
                                                                  ->  Seq Scan on skos."ConceptPrefLabel" l  (cost=0.00..1.16 rows=53 width=52) (actual time=0.004..0.010 rows=80 loops=1)
                                                                        Output: l.label, l.language, l.concept_nss
                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1
                                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1.18..1.18 rows=46 width=50) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=80 loops=1)
                                                                        Output: n."notationType", n.value, n.concept_nss
                                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 15kB
                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1
                                                                        ->  Seq Scan on skos."Notation" n  (cost=0.00..1.18 rows=46 width=50) (actual time=0.004..0.018 rows=80 loops=1)
                                                                              Output: n."notationType", n.value, n.concept_nss
                                                                              Filter: (n."notationType" = 'NutricasCode'::text)
                                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=1
                  ->  Hash  (cost=18.85..18.85 rows=242 width=58) (actual time=0.102..0.102 rows=137 loops=1)
                        Output: trcu.cuid, trta.additive
                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 19kB
                        Buffers: shared hit=2
                        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=15.72..18.85 rows=242 width=58) (actual time=0.021..0.067 rows=137 loops=1)
                              Output: trcu.cuid, trta.additive
                              Hash Cond: ((trcu.technology)::bpchar = (trta.technology)::bpchar)
                              Buffers: shared hit=2
                              ->  Seq Scan on public."CascadeUnit" trcu  (cost=0.00..1.17 rows=55 width=52) (actual time=0.006..0.013 rows=82 loops=1)
                                    Output: trcu.cuid, trcu.technology
                                    Buffers: shared hit=1
                              ->  Hash  (cost=12.64..12.64 rows=880 width=64) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=16 loops=1)
                                    Output: trta.technology, trta.additive
                                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                    Buffers: shared hit=1
                                    ->  Seq Scan on public."TechnologyAdditive" trta  (cost=0.00..12.64 rows=880 width=64) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=16 loops=1)
                                          Output: trta.technology, trta.additive
                                          Buffers: shared hit=1
```

Comment: Please do not alter the original format of the `explain (analyze)` output. Copy and paste the complete (and unaltered) text and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. To do that, paste the text output into your question, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't alter the format, I just added the output of another tool... I'll add the output of explain :).

Comment: That's not the output of an `explain (analyze)`

Comment: Exactly, it's the output of a tool which visualizes the output of explain analyze. I added it now.

Comment: 13 milliseconds seems fast enough to me. How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: I'm profiling right now, to see how much it increases when I add new cascades (there are only 21 now). The rate it is increasing is pretty exponential, and I'll need about 10-100x times more. It won't be fast enough in that case. I know, premature optimization, but it 's not premature, it's knowing now that it won't be fast enough. I want to be prepared, since in the next few months, it will happen.

Comment: Well, you need to show us the (complete) execution plan of a slow query, not of the fast one

Comment: OK, so, I understand: don't do any predictions and wait until you get really slow before optimizing, right? In that case, I just have to wait until it gets too slow.

Comment: Note `LEFT JOIN skos ...  WHERE     skos."Translations".notation = 'SimpleNotation'`

Comment: "wait until you get really slow before optimizing"  No need to wait, just dummy up some extra rows (on a non-production server of course) which makes it too slow and show us the plan for that.  It sounds like you are doing the "dummy up" already, now you just have to show us the results from it.

Comment: What is the rationale for the LEFT JOINs?  It seems like they will be identical to inner joins, as you then filter out the NULL-extended rows due to your WHERE clause. Often the planner is smart enough to figure that out, but not in this case apparently.  Or maybe they are really not identical and I'm not smart enough to see why.

Comment: True... I always start with LEFT JOINs. Most of the joins can be INNER JOINs. I just changed them and it seems to improve with 5-10%. Thx.

Comment: @jjanes yes... well, for now, I'm good for now. It runs smoothly after further optimizing. It should work fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `left join`s.  I don't even think you need aggregation:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM "CascadeStep" trcs LEFT JOIN
     "CascadeUnit" trcu 
      ON trcu.cuid = trcs.from LEFT JOIN
      "TechnologyAdditive" trta 
      ON trta.technology = trcu.technology LEFT JOIN
      skos."Translations" tfrom and tfrom.notation = 'SimpleNotation'
      ON tfrom.id = trcs.from) LEFT JOIN
      skos."Translations" tto and tto.notation = 'SimpleNotation'
      ON tto.id = trcs.to LEFT JOIN
      skos."Translations" tflow and tto.notation = 'SimpleNotation'
      ON tflow.id = trcs.flow LEFT JOIN
      skos."Translations" tproduct and tflow.notation = 'SimpleNotation'
      ON tproduct.id = trcs.product LEFT JOIN
      skos."Translations" tadditive
      ON tadditive.id = trcs.additive and tadditive.notation = 'SimpleNotation'
WHERE tto.id is not null or tflow.id is not null or
      tproduct.id is not null or tadditive is not null;
```

I'm not sure exactly what your results look like.  You may need to unpivot the data (using a lateral join) to get your exact results.  But this should fix your performance problem.

Note:  This assumes that each join to `Translations` has one match.  This seems reasonable but you might need to take duplicates into account if it is not the case.